# runing shell command inside java action on Oozie throws Permission denied

Tags: java, shell, hadoop, bigdata, oozie

I have this java code

```
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        execute("echo \"Amer\"");
    }

private static void execute(String command) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder();
    builder.command(command);
    //builder.directory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
    Process process = builder.start();

    StreamGobbler streamGobbler =
            new StreamGobbler(process.getInputStream(), System.out::println);
    Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(streamGobbler);
    int exitCode = process.waitFor();
    assert exitCode == 0;
}
```

and I am trying to run it on a Oozie workflow via java action 
but when i submit the workflow, it's killed with the following exception (java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied)

> org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaMainException: java.io.IOException:
>   Cannot run program "echo "Amer"": error=13, Permission denied     at
>   org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaMain.run(JavaMain.java:60)     at
>   org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMain.run(LauncherMain.java:78)
>     at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaMain.main(JavaMain.java:35)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMapper.map(LauncherMapper.java:231)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:465)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:349)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:174)  at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1688)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:168) Caused
>   by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "echo "Amer"": error=13,
>   Permission denied     at
>   java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)  at
>   ShellCommandExecutor.execute(ShellCommandExecutor.java:18)    at
>   ShellCommandExecutor.main(ShellCommandExecutor.java:11)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaMain.run(JavaMain.java:57)     ... 15
>   more Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied  at
>   java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)  at
>   java.lang.UNIXProcess.(UNIXProcess.java:247)    at
>   java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)     at
>   java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)  ... 22 more

any hint ?

Comment: `builder.command("sh", "-c", command);` if you want to run a shell command instead of a program with an argument array

Comment: thank you so much , it works !!